# Android sharedpreferences in each fragment or bundle from main activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, bundle

I save some data like the user id (to make requests to apirest) using sharedpreferences, next I have an activity with 3 fragments which will use this id. Should I get the data (id) getting sharedpreference in each fragment? or should I getSharedPreferences in the main activity and pass the id using bundle??

My question: which option is faster and consumes less resources?and why?

Comment: obviously is faster read from memory (ram) than read from disk. SharedPreferences work with xml

Comment: @an_droid_dev sorry my english is not good, when yo refer to memory ram you refer to use bundle? which option you recommend? can you be clearer, please?

Comment: yes, i mean Bundle. Bundle is not stored to disk but into memory (ram).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a singleton class for SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

The issue with passing it as an extra is that it may not be recovered on a Fragment re-creation. You might need to take pre-cautions by saving the value before the Fragment destroys itself to re-instantiate or any other unforeseeable event.

With that in mind it's a good idea to get the id from the `SharedPreferences`. The read operation is not as expensive as the write operation (which is why there is the asynchronous `apply()` method).

Comment: so, you recommend me to call getSharedPreferences in each fragment? to get the id?

Comment: @matQ Yes. See my first paragraph for the reasoning.